# Django/Django REST Framework - Internal API displaying results fetched from external API with filtering

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

So hey guys currently I'm trying to create an API endpoint that calls an external API via url with some filtering by comma separated strings. I'm  used to creating internal APIs with models and views that call from it's own local sqlite database. But I'm less familiar with this.

For instance I'm trying to have it so when I open my django devserver for this endpoint say called 'api/data?tags=beef,chicken' it gets the JSON response from say 'www.example.com/api/data?tags=beef,chicken' and displays it.

I was thinking about something like the code but wasn't sure how to apply filtering to it without accessing the queryset.

```
    import requests
    from rest_framework import status
    from rest_framework.response import Response


    def external_api_view(request):
        if request.method == "GET": 
            r = requests.get("https://example.com/api/data/")
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need to send the parameters directly from your local API to the external API you can use this

```py
def external_api_view(request):
        if request.method == "GET": 
            r = requests.get("https://example.com/api/data/", params=requests.GET)
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. When answering a question, you should add an explanation of what your code does and why it answers the asker's question. This way, other users who happen upon your answer can learn from it.

Comment: Hmm I'm thinking of say, splitting the internal API string of say api/data?tags=beef,chicken  and appending the string "?tags=beef,chicken" to the end of the external API call and performing a get on that?

Comment: it is not necessary, just indicate the params attribute in the request is enough